# SwiftUI LazyVGrid spacing not working as expected

Tags: swift, swiftui, lazyvgrid

The following results in a grid with no vertical spacing (correct), but with 20px horizontal spacing between each item in the grid. What am I doing wrong? I don't want any spacing whatsoever in between items.

```
private var columnGrid: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), spacing: 0), count: 15)

var body: some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columnGrid, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(Array(viewModel.array.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { character in
            SomeView(char: character.element)
                .background(.red)
        }
    }
    .background(.green)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show the output you currently have? Before that, if you add `.background` modifiers with distinctive colors to `LazyVGrid` and `SomeView`, it will help to find out where exactly the unwanted spacing appears.

Comment: It's expected behavior in case when if your `SomeView` doesn't have enough width, for example try adding `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`

Comment: @lazarevzubov I updated the question with the background modifiers and an image.

Comment: @PylypDukhov thanks for the suggestion. It didn't solve the problem though.

Comment: Have you added it to `SomeView`? It should be added before `background(.red)`. If this still doesn't help, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `SomeView()` content is not taking up all available space. Somewhere in it you could use:

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Here is da demo:

```
private var columnGrid: [GridItem] =
    Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), spacing: 0), count: 15)

var body: some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columnGrid, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(0..<40) { character in
            Text("\(character)")
                .frame(height: 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // here
                .border(.primary, width: 1)
                .background(.gray)
        }
    }
    .background(.green)
    .padding()
}
```

[image]